# How to upgrade QGIS Capiapo to Lisboa?

Tags: qgis, update

I want to upgrade my QGIS version to the newest one, Lisboa, but I'm not sure if I should uninstall Capiapo first. Is there a way to upgrade without uninstalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two versions can be installed in parallel, but the connection of file appendix .qgs will be set to the latest installation.

The older version may break if plugins will be installed that are not compatible with that.